# Java application packaging without IDEs

Tags: java

I have a java application which runs in CMD and I am running it in our traditional way like :

```
javac test.java
java test
```

I have added some libraries also in my root as a folder, those are inside a folder named 'org', all dependencies are inside that. I need to package this application and make it work on client machine. How can I do that? I do not use any IDEs.

Comment: You can create JAR file manually http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html but I suggest using build system like Maven or Ant

Comment: Check out Ant, Gradle or Maven

Answer (score 3):

generally there is always a build manager associated with a project, for example maven or ant which abstracts out the complexity of managing dependency and packaging

I would mavenize project

Answer (score 2):

1. Compile your java classes and add them to a jar to handle them easier. As an alternative you can also include your bin directory with your compiled classed if you like.
2. Put your libraries in a folder (so your org folder)
3. Create a bat (Windows) or shell script (Unix) that bundles all together to a CLASSPATH and calls your main class. One example for such a batch script can be found here (old project from me):
   http://sourceforge.net/p/emailarchiving/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/SMTPProxy/build/run.bat
   That project also contains a manifest and a sample unix script. It is a standalone Java application.

This a manual process without any kind of maven or ant support. However those tools will make your life easier in the long run.

Comment: I have created a jar file using this command 'jar cvf Count.jar Count.class'. Then I created a Folder named Project and added my org folder and my newly created jar file inside it. Can you tell your 3rd step? Now I have a folder contains jar and org.

Comment: In the end you need a command like
java -classpath "Count.jar;org/library1.jar;org/library2.jar" <your class name>
And the bat file that I referred to builds this command and includes your libraries (adjust to your needs).

Comment: java -classpath "Count.jar;org/library1.jar;org/library2.jar" Count. I am getting error like Count not find or load main class Count

Comment: Whats your exact commandline action and what is the full name to your java class incl. package?

Comment: @Cartsen I am working with xbasej. I added that library in my java file. I did extracted all the support files and did it inside a folder org and an extra file log4j thats in root itself. Now I have test.java and log4j and folder org in my root where im running my test.java. In my system its working. I need it to deploy to client system so he can also run from cmd, but I need to bundle it as a package, so I did as you suggested I created my test.classs to jar and try to run that jar file and I am getting error no main manifest attribute in "test.jar"

Comment: Yes that is correct as you need to add a manifest to a jar.
An example manifest can be found in this folder:
http://sourceforge.net/p/emailarchiving/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/SMTPProxy/build/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63213/discussion-between-androidgenx-and-carsten).

Comment: I have added a manifest file and made jar again still not working

Answer (score 1):

There are many options that you have, e.g.

- [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/)
- [Gradle](http://www.gradle.org/)
- [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/)
- or just using the [Java Archive Tool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jar.html)

There is also a [comparision of the most used tools](http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/java-build-tools-part-2-a-decision-makers-comparison-of-maven-gradle-and-ant-ivy/) available on rebellabs. Maybe this helps to make a decision.

**comparision sheet from rebellabs**

[image: Image from Zeroturnaround.com (Rebellabs)]

Comment: I do not want to use IDEs, can you suggest any other method, will be helpful

Comment: @androidGenX These are _build tools_ and although they all fit into an IDE, they are all independent of it.

Comment: Even if there are also IDE integrations you can use all of them without an IDE as @Seelenvirtuose mentioned. But maybe IDE integration is a point on your decision list.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create Application Structure as follows

   MyFiles
       - ABC.class (File)
       - images (Folder)
       - musics (Folder)
2. get inside of Myfiles from MS DOS

   jar cvf MyFiles.jar ABC.class images musics 
   //jar cvf TicTacToe.jar *